# Is there a way to avoid SignalR when uploading files in Blazor Server-Side

Tags: javascript, c#, azure, signalr, blazor

I have a **Blazor App (server-side)** that is hosted in **Azure** as an **App Service**, I use **Azure SignalR Service** to be able to scale the amount of users being connected at the same time. I also have a page where you can upload files, the files might be large, even 1GB and more, I'm using **Tewr.Blazor.FileReader (Nuget)** to read the file in chunks and upload it to an API that saves the file to the server. **But I was wondering if it's possible to avoid the SignalR part** in some way when uploading the file, because for 2GB file, **Azure SignalR breaks each message to 2KB/each**, which means I hit the limit of **1M messages/day/unit**, ***just for uploading 1 file***.
Let me know of all the ways I can approach this problem, currently I've few solutions in mind:

- Have separate **SignalR App** hosted as **App Service** instead of using **Azure SignalR**
- **iframe** that page to **ASP.NET Core App** that **only handles the transfer of the files**. (*Not sure if this will trigger SignalR traffic*)

Comment: Did you tried to change `ApplicationMaxBufferSize` and `TransportMaxBufferSize` in SignalR configurations. [There is a library vendor sample](https://github.com/Tewr/BlazorFileReader#optional-signalr-configuration-for-large-buffer-sizes)

Comment: @ASpirin That won't solve the problem, it affect the upload speed when using built-in SignalR, but Azure SignalR by default breaks down any messages larger than 2KBs to 2KB/each and processes them. (I can have 10MB chunk, but it'll get broken down when it reaches Azure SignalR Service)

Comment: Are you sure you want this through SignalR? As apposed to a normal HTTP API endpoint?

Comment: Have you tried adding stone JavsScript to read the file in the browser and then http post it to the api endpoint directly?

Comment: @HenkHolterman I definitely want to use normal HTTP API Endpoint, but that's the question, how do I achieve it, as far as I know everything goes through SignalR with Blazor Server-Side

Comment: @PeterMorris I believe it will still generate SignalR traffic, or it won't? Otherwise I had that idea in mind, but wasn't sure.

Comment: @Vex - yes, you don't want a copy-loop in C#. Peters idea sounds right, but I'm no JS expert. I'll add a tag.

Comment: Here is an interesting read on this problem: https://blog.stevensanderson.com/2019/09/13/blazor-inputfile/

Comment: @vex No it won't go over SignalR. JavaScript in the browser executes independently.

Comment: @PeterMorris Yep I will test that, I believe so too, when I think about it...
PS: I just thought that it will go over IJSRuntime and generate traffic thru there, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use standard DOM events (e.g. `onchanged=someJavaSciptFunction`) then the Browser will run JavaScript in response to that event.

If you set the appropriate JS script on your UI elements then you can have the JS make an HTTP request to your API. This will avoid SignalR completely.

Answer (score 0):

You could upload the file to a Web API controller. You can even add the controller in the same project.
I think this approach is used by the [DevExpress Blazor FileUpload](https://demos.devexpress.com/blazor/Upload).

But it should be easy to implement it yourself. You need some javascript that POSTs the file content to your Web API controller. [This blog entry](https://remibou.github.io/Upload-file-with-Blazor/) could help you.